# Android complaining about content not having Listview with id android.R.id.List despite having that

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, r.java-file

obviously not a profound question, but I think theres probably an error in my approach.

So I've added the file listview.xml to my project in the layout folder.

it contains this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

I've also tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

And i my main activity function generally looks like this:

```
public class ToDoManagerActivity extends ListActivity {

private static final int ADD_TODO_ITEM_REQUEST = 0;
private static final String FILE_NAME = "TodoManagerActivityData.txt";
private static final String TAG = "Lab-UserInterface";

// IDs for menu items
private static final int MENU_DELETE = Menu.FIRST;
private static final int MENU_DUMP = Menu.FIRST + 1;

ToDoListAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Create a new TodoListAdapter for this ListActivity's ListView
    mAdapter = new ToDoListAdapter(getApplicationContext());

    // Put divider between ToDoItems and FooterView
    getListView().setFooterDividersEnabled(true);

    // TODO - Inflate footerView for footer_view.xml file         
    TextView footerView = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer_view, null);

    // NOTE: You can remove this block once you've implemented the assignment
    if (null == footerView) {
        return;
    }
    // TODO - Add footerView to ListView
    getListView().addFooterView(footerView);
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);

    setContentView(R.layout.footer_view);
```

This keeps breaking with the error:

```
...java.lang.RunTimeException: content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

I noticed that if I comment out the `setContentView(R.layout.footer_view)` bit the error disappears, which is quite confusing as well, because it seems like the error should trigger before there.

This is confusing the hell out of me because as far as I can tell this element exists.  Its seems like maybe I'm missing a step to load the ListView? I'm banging my head against the wall here and this seems like something really basic, and being a n00b sucks...So any help is much appreciated!

Cheers!

EDIT:

footer_view.xml contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/footerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/add_new_todo_item_string"
    android:textSize="24sp" >

</TextView>
```

EDIT2:

Current onCreate after suggested edits:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Create a new TodoListAdapter for this ListActivity's ListView
    mAdapter = new ToDoListAdapter(getApplicationContext());

    // Put divider between ToDoItems and FooterView
    getListView().setFooterDividersEnabled(true);

    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    TextView footerView = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer_view, getListView(), false);
    getListView().addFooterView(footerView);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an Activity that is extending ListActivity, the ListView needs to exist within the xml file that you are using in the activity, in your case that's the `footer_view` file.

Taken from the [Google Dev Site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) - "ListActivity has a default layout that consists of a single, full-screen list in the center of the screen. However, if you desire, you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout with setContentView() in onCreate(). `To do this, your own view MUST contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list"`"

To incorporate your footer below your list, try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/footerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/add_new_todo_item_string"
        android:textSize="24sp" >

    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: so does the ListView tag then also have to reside in a LinearLayout tag?  Currently footer_view.xml is just an unwrapped TextView.  I'll update the question.

Comment: adding a listview to the footer_view.xml file allowed it to compile, but the footer_view isn't being rendered.

Comment: Just like Alex pointed out - your view contained in setContentView(some_layout.xml) needs to wrap your `list` in a layout of some type - a LinearLayout will work just fine for this.

Comment: @Rooster If your footer view is merely a text view then all you need to do is add it in your new LinearLayout, presumably beneath the ListView.. see my updated answer.

Comment: ah, ya.  that does the trick.  thanx.  i apparently inherited a badly structured view attempt :p

Answer (score 1):

Here, try this in your layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:id="@android:id/list" />

</LinearLayout>
```

That is exactly what I have in my app.

Then in your `onCreate()`, just this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Try it and let me know if it works. That code should work. From there, we can continue on to isolate the problem.

EDIT:

Man, now I see your problem. Not a big deal here. Let's look at your code (edited to be shorter). The `onCreate()` method has this:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
mAdapter = new ToDoListAdapter(getApplicationContext());
getListView().setFooterDividersEnabled(true);      
TextView footerView = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer_view, null);
getListView().addFooterView(footerView);
setListAdapter(mAdapter);
setContentView(R.layout.footer_view);
```

Do you see `R.layout.activity_main` anywhere there? There's your issue! Your `R.layout.footer_view` only contains a textview, it doesn't contain the `ListView`, and your Activity keeps looking for the `ListView` that you promised it that you'd have by extending a `ListActivity`.

Try this - change your `onCreate()` method to this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mAdapter = new ToDoListAdapter(getApplicationContext());
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

Then your activity_main.xml layout file should look like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:id="@android:id/list" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This should work. Let me know.

EDIT2:

Now add this to the end of your `onCreate()` method:

```
 TextView footerView = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer_view, null);
getListView().addFooterView(footerView);
```

Voila! Should work now.

Comment: which layout should that go in? I don't have an activity_main layout.

Comment: @Rooster AHHH I just noticed your problem. Give me like 30 seconds and then take another glance at my post - I'll edit it.

Comment: @Rooster All right, Rooster. That took longer than 30 seconds, but it's done. Try it - then we can work on adding a footer

Comment: @Rooster We're not done here. Now see my edit and try what I say. If it works, great. The answer is correct :)

Comment: still not seeing the footer_view being rendered.  My updated onCreate is in the edited question.  Ive also verified the string value listed in the footer_view exists.  note that small differences in the method arguments were me playing around with different versions of those methods.  rest assured I originally tried your suggestions.  Also, I can verify the list view is at least loading as i switched the bacground to white and visually verified.